# Display more than one row from SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to display all of the rows shown in the picture where `CID = 1`.
Here is my PHP code with SQL:
`

```
$contractCount = 1;

$sql = "SELECT categories.categoryID
        FROM categories
        LEFT JOIN link
        ON categories.categoryID = link.categoryID
        WHERE link.CID = '$contractCount'";

$res = $con->query($sql);
if (!$res) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['categoryID'];
}
```

Here is an image showing the table in PHPMyAdmin called **categories**.
[image]

So I need output as  `ITSM, Mar and HrAd` but I am only getting `ITSM` and not the rest.

**EDIT 1:** The LEFT JOIN makes no difference here, the link table has no bearing on the SELECT statement 
 
**EDIT 2:** I have solved the problem, my mistake was that I had the table names the wrong way round in the SQL query.

Comment: you should use prepared statements.

Comment: How many records do you have in the catagories table that have a matching categoryID with the categoryID  in the link table and that have their CID as 1?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the function [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), this will fetch a row and move the pointer to the next one.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo $row['categoryID'];
}
```